# Datasets in my silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight

I have Datamodel where I have used a DataSet as my data container.

I have a UI that is created in Silverlight.

I know that in SL 2 we cannot use Dataset. Can we use Dataset in Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Dataset's aren't directly supported in Silverlight 4. Entity model allows for much more easier form of managing changes and it comes in in-build CRUD operations. Entities works flawlessly with silverlight controls.

Fortunately, there are many workarounds available in the internet for Datasets thought. [Here's](http://silverlightdataset.net/silverlightdataset/Default.aspx) one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not manage local databases/connections, so DataSet does not exist in Silverlight (including Silverlight 4).

The objects RIA services provide do a good job of manage changes so it would make sense to convert your app to use RIA Services and change your data model to use the RIA objects.

*What feature of the DataSet do you require?* If you can post a specific example of your data and how it is used we might be able to post a more detailed solution.